# Confused by tenant, project, user, account in openstack and swift

Tags: openstack, keystore, openstack-swift, openstack-keystone

I am confused by `tenant` in openstack and swift.

I have multiple machines on C3 under tenant called `myTenant`. Here `tenant` is the same with `project`. **I cannot understand what do `tenant` and `project` mean here.**

I also have a swift container, which I can access by `tenantID` and `username`, `password` and `storageUrl`. **what are the differences between `tenant` here and `myTenant` mentioned above.**

I used `swift stat -v <containerName>` and got the `Account` of the container is `KEY_<tenantId>`. **here what is the difference between `tenant`, `user` and `Account`?**

The `storageUrl` looks like `http://ip/KEY_<tenantId>`, which is the endpoint of one container. **So, `tenantId` is limited to only one container here?**

Thanks. Any hints welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historical reasons (and the fact that it is impossible to retrospectively fix N years of legacy documentation, blogs, Q&A sites and other web-searchable stuff), some of the OpenStack terminology is a bit confusing.

The terms "tenant" and "project" mean the same thing; see this Q&A on the "Ask OpenStack" site:

- https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/84073/tenant-vs-project/

The term "tenant" is being phased out ... slowly.

So to answer your questions:

> I have multiple machines on C3 under tenant called myTenant. Here tenant is the same with project. I cannot understand what do tenant and project mean here.

See above.

> I also have a swift container, which I can access by tenantID and username, password and storageUrl. what are the differences between tenant here and myTenant mentioned above.

A "tenant" (or "project") has a name and an ID.  Your "myTenant" is a project name. The tenant ID or project ID is a long unique identifier.  You can lookup the ID for a project using the `openstack` command; e.g. `openstack project show myTenant`.

> I used `swift stat -v <containerName>` and got the Account of the container is `KEY_<tenantId>`. here what is the difference between tenant, user and Account?

A "tenant" or "project" in Keystone corresponds to an "account" in Swift.  A "user" in Keystone corresponds to a "user" in Swift.

(Strictly speaking the concepts are not identical. It is possible to run Swift with TempAuth middleware which gets identity information from local configs rather than from a Keystone service.  But that approach is designed for stand-alone testing, not production.)